# How to fix incorrectly encoded string?

Tags: python, sql-server, r, encoding, character-encoding

I have a table in SQL Server which is populated with some incorrectly encoded characters. When I had the source, I found out that the source is also problematic. I don't have the correctly encoded data (i.e. correct representation of these). I'm hoping that there is one-to-one relationship among encoding systems so somehow I can decode the chars and find the correct encoding.

So far I was partially able to encode, but it was obviously wrong, see below for example,

`Autã³Noma De Ciudad Juã¡Rez` -> `Auta3Noma De Ciudad Jua!Rez`
`Plutarco ElÃ­as Calle` -> `Plutarco ElA-as Calles`
`Tecnolã³Gico` -> `Tecnola3Gico`

I did this in R with,

```
iconv('GÃ¡lvez QuiÃ±ones', to='ASCII//TRANSLIT')
[1] "GA!lvez QuiA?ones"
```

As you see, I've not succeeded yet. Do you think correctly encoding these incorrectly encoded characters is doable in R, Python or SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Hey this is a **PARTIAL** solution, i.e. it doesn't deal well/fix some characters (e.g. superscript-3, inverse exclamation point, A with ~). But it works well with the other 2. I used `iconv` and changed the `to` encoding.

```
universidades<- c("Autã³Noma De Ciudad Juã¡Rez", 
         "Plutarco ElÃ­as Calle", "Tecnolã³Gico", "GÃ¡lvez QuiÃ±ones")
universidades
    [1] "Autã³Noma De Ciudad Juã¡Rez" "Plutarco ElÃ­as Calle"      
    [3] "Tecnolã³Gico"                "GÃ¡lvez QuiÃ±ones"          
iconv(universidades, to="latin-9")
    [1] "Aut\xe3\xb3Noma De Ciudad Ju\xe3\xa1Rez"
    [2] "Plutarco Elías Calle"                   
    [3] "Tecnol\xe3\xb3Gico"                     
    [4] "Gálvez Quiñones"
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though it is a late reply. Hope this will be helpful for anyone else..
In Python we can use the below code

```
    import ftfy
    from unidecode import unidecode
    fixtext = ftfy.fix_text('Autã³Noma De Ciudad Juã¡Rez')
    print(unidecode(fixtext))
```